# Cannot bind parameter 'Start' to the target. Exception setting "Start": "Cannot convert null to type "System.DateTime"."

Tags: powershell

Here is my code:

```
function Execute-Script($path) {
      $key = (3,4,2,3,56,34,254,222,1,1,2,23,42,54,33,233,1,34,2,7,6,5,35,43)
      trap { "failed"; break }
      $raw = Get-Content $path
      $secure = ConvertTo-SecureString $raw -Key $key
      $helper = New-Object system.Management.Automation.PSCredential("asapkal", $secure)
      $plain = $helper.GetNetworkCredential().Password
      Invoke-Expression $plain
    }
    Execute-Script "D:\PDMReport\PDMReport.bin"
```

and I am getting below error:

```
Invoke-Expression : Cannot bind parameter 'Start' to the target. Exception setting "Start": "Cannot convert null to type "System.DateTime"."
At line:8 char:3
+   Invoke-Expression $plain
+   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : WriteError: (:) [Invoke-Expression], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterBindingFailed,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeExpressionCommand
```

Please help with the resolution, I tried running ISE with administrator but error is still there.

Comment: Hard to say without knowing the contents of `D:\PDMReport\PDMReport.bin`

Comment: Your code executes `$plain`, which seems to contain a _password_. Is that the intent? Also: [`Invoke-Expression` should generally be avoided](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/powershell/2011/06/03/invoke-expression-considered-harmful/)

Comment: As an aside: Please avoid pseudo method syntax: instead of `New-Object SomeType(arg1, ...)`, use `New-Object SomeType [-ArgumentList] arg1, ...` - PowerShell cmdlets, scripts and functions are invoked like _shell commands_, not like _methods_. That is, no parentheses around the argument list, and _whitespace_-separated arguments (`,` constructs an _array_ as a _single argument_, as needed for `-ArgumentList`).

Comment: Unless you show us what is in all these variables, or should be, it's not possible to help. If you step through this with just a sample file to read, of course, this whole thing errors out.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `Invoke-Expression $plain` use `Write-Host $plain` and you will see where the problem is.

If it will still not be clear, post the output here (if not confidential) and you may get further help.